# How to create publicly readable object store containers with ruby openstack gem?

Tags: ruby, openstack

I have tried to create publicly readable openstack object store containers like this:

```
os = OpenStack::Connection.create(...)      
container = os.create_container(container_name)
container.set_metadata({'X-Container-Read' => '.r:*'})
```

Using my code above, the newly created containers are private.

What is the correct way to create containers with public read permissions with the ruby openstack gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following way.

You can redfine the [create_container](https://github.com/ruby-openstack/ruby-openstack/blob/3ab55bcebedd7a96119a9d7567dee9df3f1d5989/lib/openstack/swift/connection.rb#L126) method

then

```
class MyStack < OpenStack::Swift::Connection
  def create_container(containername)
   super
   @connection.req("PUT", path, {:headers=>{"Content-Length"=>"0", "X-Container-Read" => ".r:*", "X-Container-Write" => ".r:*}})
   OpenStack::Swift::Container.new(self, containername)
 end
end
```

These `"X-Container-Read" => ".r:*", "X-Container-Write" => ".r:*"` header value you need to set.

or

```
container.set_metadata({"X-Container-Read" => ".r:*", "X-Container-Write" => ".r:*"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

From the two alternative approaches you provided, only the first one seems to work in my case. I opened the OpenStack gem and added the extra header "X-Container-Read" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
module PubliclyRedableContainerMonkeyPatch
  def create_publicy_readable_container(containername)
    raise OpenStack::Exception::InvalidArgument.new("Container name cannot contain '/'") if containername.match("/")
    raise OpenStack::Exception::InvalidArgument.new("Container name is limited to 256 characters") if containername.length > 256
    path = "/#{URI.encode(containername.to_s)}"
    @connection.req("PUT", path, {:headers=>{"Content-Length"=>"0", "X-Container-Read" => ".r:*"}})
    OpenStack::Swift::Container.new(self, containername)
  end
end

OpenStack::Swift::Connection.include PubliclyRedableContainerMonkeyPatch

os = OpenStack::Connection.create(...)                
container = os.create_publicy_readable_container(container_name)
```

Worksforme. :)